# A Objective-C Method that outputs text into a Blank Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, calendar, label

Sorry for the vague title, but I'll explain in the text here:

I've been in the process of making an iOS app that tells me what sort of day it is at my school (we run on a 7 day rotation, with 5 days of classes). It gets somewhat hard to remember the day and your schedule for the day, so I wanted to make an app for myself and colleagues. I've got most of the UI sorted out, but the final and most important part, the display of the day itself, I can't figure out. What I want to do is take the date, check it against a repository of dates that gives the text for that day(for example, having the input be 2014,27,9 would yield the text "No School"). I would then like to somehow get that text to show up in the content of an already existing label. Is this possible? And if it is, what would I need to do to make it work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So what have you done? It sounds like you need help with the entire app. Questions here must cover a single topic. So redo your question to cover just one issue. Provide details of what you have done and what you need help with.

Comment: So basically you want help with your homework?

Comment: It's not homework, it's for personal use. Also in response to rmaddy, the only thing I need help with is getting the text to display in the label, not anything else.

Comment: What part of setting a label's text do you need help with? Simply set the `text` property of the label. That's pretty simple.

Comment: How can I do that with a method though?

Comment: Again, clarify what you have done. Update your question with some relevant code. Clearly show where you are having an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really provide much information, so I'll just include everything from the bottom up and you can jump to the step you're stuck at.

1. In your view controllers header file (probably ViewController.h) in the @interface section you're going to want to create a new label that can be used in interface builder, `IBOutlet UILabel *displayLabel;`
2. Next go to your view in interface builder and drag a new label onto your view.
3. At the top of your view right click and hold your View Controller (yellow ish icon) and drag your mouse over to the label and let go, a new window should pop up and you should be able to select displayLabel as the Outlet.
4. Pop over to your ViewController.m file and wherever your function is that returns the text for the day add the code `displayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@", RETURNEDSTRING];` where RETURNEDSTRING is the name of the string that is holding your returned text.

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat:` in step 4? Just directly assign the string.